# Different Trace Id between applications on spring boot 2 and spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, micrometer-tracing

I have several Spring Boot applications, one of which is using Spring Boot 3 and the others are using Spring Boot 2.The request get originated from Spring Boot 3 and goes to Spring Boot 2 component

The issue I am facing is trace id are different across application. I went through almost all the solution suggested still different trace id.

In Spring Boot 3 application.yml

```
management: 
   tracing:
     propagation:
       type: b3
     sampling:
       probability: 1.0
```

In Spring Boot 2 application.yml

```
 spring.sleuth.traceId128: true
 spring.sleuth.supportsJoin: false
 spring.sleuth.propagation.type: w3c,b3
```

Comment: Have you added this property in Spring Boot 3 application? `logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]`. Also, please check if you have added all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 3 defaults to the `W3C` Trace Context format, while Spring Boot 2 defaults to the `B3` format. If not properly configured, the consumer app might not recognize or parse the W3C format, leading to a new trace ID being generated

All you need to do is correctly define the propagation properties for the Spring Boot 2 app as following

```
spring.sleuth.propagation.type=W3C,B3
```

Please note that properties are in Uppercase. you have defined it in lowercase